# Get Facebook access_token with Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, facebook-c#-sdk

Hi I'm new with Facbook c#SDK.
has someone an example of a Facebook log in and get the access_token token.
I use Facebook SDK v6 and Silverligt 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JavaScript API to get your token and then AJAX it to your server.

Please also read up on the SDK here: http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started on how to store your token server-side for use.

Also, try to do as much with the API using the JavaScript API SDK provided by Facebook (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).  It is very powerful and will lessen the load on your server if you do the calls client side rather than server side.